# How to compute $\int_0^s \frac{r\, \mathrm{d}r}{\sqrt{s^2-r^2}\sqrt{t^2-r^2}}$ if we know that $s<t$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals, integral-equations, integral-transforms

In a integral equation problem, I came across the following integral
$$
\phi(s,t) = \int_0^s \frac{r\, \mathrm{d}r}{\sqrt{s^2-r^2}\sqrt{t^2-r^2}} \, .
$$

We can remark that the integral is given by
$$
\phi(s,t) = \frac{1}{2} \ln \left( \frac{t+s}{t-s} \right) \, .
$$

But is there a way to prove that analytically, provided that $s < t$?

Thanks

R

Comment: $$rdr=1/2 dr^2$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the change of variable $\tau = r^2$ and the following indefinite integral
$$
\int \frac{d\tau}{\sqrt{\tau^2-a\tau+b}}
=\ln\left(\frac{a}{2}-\tau-\sqrt{\tau^2-a\tau+b}\right).
$$
Then
\begin{align}
\int_0^s \frac{r\, \mathrm{d}r}{\sqrt{s^2-r^2}\sqrt{t^2-r^2}}
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{s^2}\frac{d\tau}{\sqrt{\tau^2-(s^2+t^2)\tau+s^2t^2}} \cr
&=\left.\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{s^2+t^2}{2}-\tau-\sqrt{\tau^2-(s^2+t^2)\tau+s^2t^2}\right)
\right|_{\tau=0}^{s^2} \cr
&= \frac{1}{2}\ln\left( \frac{t+s}{t-s}\right).
\end{align}